# <context:componentscan> how does it work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can "context: componentscan" scan custom annotations? If so, where does it store the scanned beans in application context after scanning? How can I access the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We register beans or components in XML configuration file. So Spring can detect those beans, components. Spring also support to auto scan, detect and instantiate beans from pre-defined project package via the annotation. So we don't have to declare in the configuration anymore. For example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="abc.controller, abc.service" />
```

in your Controller or Service, you just have to add annotation like:

```
@Controller
public class SampleController

@Service
public class SampleService
```

Spring will know that your SampleController and SamplerService and you can use it as you want.

Some detail here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html

Comment: Hello Kenny,Thanks for your explanation. I have a set of custom annotations, can the above component-scan scans it? and if yes, then where does it store in application context and how can i access them?

Comment: I think you can check the detail here: http://techo-ecco.com/blog/spring-custom-annotations/

Comment: Hi kenny,It was helpful but it was returning a proxy bean instead of normal bean. Finally got the plain target class using AOPUtils.getTargetClass(Object obj)....